# $PATH doesn't show .bash_profile, only shows /etc/paths

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, path

I have a beautifully set `.bash_profile` and everything was working well, then I updated to zsh. I installed Visual Studio for Mac, for a while I didn't realise that something was wrong, today I saw that all my paths were gone and I could only see the ones below when I `echo`:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
```

It's what I have in `/etc/paths` and my Visual Studio paths.
Now I tried setting the `source`, but this only works during the current session, when I close and open my terminal again, it resets back to this broken one.

I looked through my files, I don't have a `.profile` or a `.bashrc` either. I even tried turning my Mac off and on again.

my `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:$PATH"
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=/Users/me/flutter/bin:$PATH
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

How can I make my Terminal just read `.bash_profile`?

Comment: Your $PATH is not broken but it contains the standard paths after installing a subset of Visual Studio for Mac (system defaults & Mono, dotnet). What's the content of your *.bash_profile*?

Comment: @klanomath I have added my .bash_profile to the question. I also assumed it was like you said but I couldn't find anywhere how Visual Studio does this.

Comment: What is in the nvm.sh script? It could be overwriting the path when you source it. Maybe try moving all the nvm loading stuff to before your export statements?

Comment: just tried that now @compuphys it does no effect unfortunately. The same thing is happening. That last part is just to run nvm as far as I know.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here then but you can try using the following links to hunt down the problem. [Determine the type of shell you're in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26782), then [look at this flow chart](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/) to see which files are loaded and in which order.

Comment: @compuphys It's `interactive` and `not login shell` but I am not sure what to do with this information. Should I create `/etc/bash.bashrc` and put everything inside it?

Comment: Oh well, actually that doesn't work either, I am completely lost here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who experiences this issue, I apparently it was broken after my zsh update.

Found the solution [here](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/3807):

> `.bash_profile` is a file read only by bash, which is not compatible with zsh. If we start sourcing `.bash_profile` bad things will start to happen. Instead, you should copy those ENV vars to the `.zshrc` file, preferably at the end of it.

Apparently you have to put everything into `.zshrc` instead of `.bash_profile` after this update. Some things might work a little different, btw, e.g. `PROMPT` colors. That wasn't an issue in this case, though.

Note that like with bash, there's a bunch of other files that may be sourced depending on the kind of shell you open that can contain various different settings, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/71253) for a related question.

Comment: Ahh. You really should have mentioned you were using `zsh` and not `bash` ...

Comment: To be a bit nitpicky: Nobody is going to experience the issue from the question as that wasn't the issue that happened. :) If I get your self-answer right it was merely a coincidence that you installed MS VS around the time you updated to Catalina, right? Because that was what changed the default shell from bash to zsh. I suggest you update your question accordingly, then that will surely help others in the future! Btw, welcome to the community!

Comment: @compuphys sorry about that you are right like Gero said it was a complete coincidence for me and I didn't realise what's happening. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Gero you are right, I will update it accordingly